# CVS causing Grails problems in Intellij IDEA

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, cvs

I've had a lot of bizarre conflicts with my Grails (2.0.3) project using Intellij IDEA (11.1.3). My project is hooked up to our CVS repoitory. I finally traced my problems down to CVS creating a `CVS\Base` folder whenever I edit a file.

My problems arise because Grails finds conflicting copies of my `.groovy` files and chokes. For example, I edit `MyDomain.groovy` to add a new field and CVS creates a `CVS\Base\MyDomain.class` backup of the file. Grails tries to load both and throws various exceptions depending on the change.

I can't find any CVS settings in IDEA that control the creation of these backups. *I don't want them and I just delete them manually*. I also don't know how to get IDEA to add these to the exclude list. I've gone into Project Settings, but I can't find the folders to exclude them. I think because the `.\CVS` sub-folder is hidden from view by default, that the `Base` sub-folder is also inaccessible.

Ideally, I'd like to know how to...

- ...stop CVS from creating this `Base` folder
- ...get Grails to ignore the folder if it is there.

---

CrazyCoder has correctly pointed out that this is not an issue with IntelliJ IDEA specifically, but a [known issue with Grails](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-3336), but that still doesn't help me resolve my issue.

**If you are having similar issues**, please go to the [Grails Jira page for this issue](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-3336) and add your comments and vote for this issue. **If you have a workaround for this**, then post the workaround as your answer.

Answer (score 2):

IDEA is already ignoring `CVS` folders by default, the [bug is in Grails](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-3336).

Comment: It is not very comforting to know that this issue has been around for four years. I added a comment to the Jira issue. Knowing that it is a known issue doesn't help me though. If there isn't a way to tell IDEA to also ignore CVS\Base, is there a way to get CVS to stop creating these folders?

Comment: IDEA is ignoring these folders, however IDEA cannot tell Grails to ignore them as there is no such option for Grails command line tools. You also can't remove these directories as it's how CVS stores its metadata.

Comment: I disagree about removing the `Base` directories. Since they are causing Grails conflicts, I've been deleting them manually as they are created. The main metadata is stored in `.\CVS` in the `Entries`, `Repository`, and `Root` files. Based on [this description of CVS files](http://durak.org/sean/pubs/software/cvsbook/Working-Copy-Files.html), the `.\CVS\Base` folder is for copies of the original file, so you can work if the server is unavailable. I'm not concerned with that and IDEA does a great job diff'ing any file revisions. I need CVS to stop creating the `Base` folder.